# Error: ‘__forceinline__’ does not name a type in TensorFlow

Tags: c++, makefile, macros, tensorflow

I'm building tensorflow on Ubuntu14.04, but having this error message. 
Some flag or macros was missing? Do you have any insight about this error?

```
In file included from 
/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/gcuda.cc:16:0:
/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/gcuda.h:234:1: error: ‘__forceinline__’ does not name a type
 __forceinline__ __device__ clock_t __gcuda_nvcc_clock() { return clock(); }
 ^
/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/gcuda.h:235:1: error: ‘__forceinline__’ does not name a type
 __forceinline__ __device__ int __gcuda_nvcc__clz(int x) {
 ^
/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/gcuda.h:238:1: error: ‘__forceinline__’ does not name a type
 __forceinline__ __device__ int __gcuda_nvcc__clzll(long long int x) {
 ^
/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/gcuda.h:241:1: error: ‘__forceinline__’ does not name a type
 __forceinline__ __device__ float __gcuda_nvcc__fdividef(float a, float b) {
 ^
/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/gcuda.h:244:1: error: ‘__forceinline__’ does not name a type
 __forceinline__ __device__ int __gcuda_nvcc__ffsll(long long int x) { // NOLINT
 ^
/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/gcuda.h:247:1: error: ‘__forceinline__’ does not name a type
 __forceinline__ __device__ int __gcuda_nvcc__popc(unsigned int x) {
 ^
/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/gcuda.h:250:1: error: ‘__forceinline__’ does not name a type
 __forceinline__ __device__ float __gcuda_nvcc__powf(float a, float b) {
 ^
/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/gcuda.h:253:1: error: ‘__forceinline__’ does not name a type
 __forceinline__ __device__ void __gcuda_nvcc__sincosf( ...
```

Comment: For build issues, it's best to ask them on our github page: https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues. Please include the `bazel` build command.

Comment: Actually, I already asked here, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5465. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, thanks! Following up there.